# C# UNITY Instantiate Class (Create Object) without using new operator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

example I have class name "PlayerClass" and "StatClass"

## PlayerClass

```
public float health = 100 ;
public float experience;
```

## StatClass

```
PlayerClass playerclass = new PlayerClass()
public float health2;
public float experience2;
health2 = playerclass.health;
experience2 = playerclas.experience;
```

usually I have to create "PlayerClass playerclass = new PlayerClass()"

the result will be the same health2 and experience2;
but whenever i made a change on healt from player class with code of course, the result healt2 from StatClass will be the same it was 100

Sory for my bad english.

----------------- Edited -----

## GameControl

```
public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public static GameControl control;

    public float health = 100;
    public float experience = 1000;
    // Use this for initialization

    void Awake () {
        /*
         * Awake Start Before Start() Happen
         */
        if (control == null) {
            DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
            control = this;
        } else if (control != this) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

## GetHealth

```
public class GetHealth : MonoBehaviour {

    public static GetHealth getHealth;
    GameControl gameControl = new GameControl();
    //GameControl gameControl;

    public static float health;
    Text text;

    void Awake () {
        /*
         * Awake Start Before Start() Happen
         */

        if (getHealth == null) {
            DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
            getHealth = this;
        } else if (getHealth != this) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }

        text = GetComponent<Text> ();
        health = 0;
    }

    void Update(){
        health = gameControl.health;
        text.text = "Health: " + health;
    }
}
```

I made Change on value variable Health in GameControl. but Get Health always access 100 the same as first time when variable GameControl haven't changed. I think it was maybe because we use "new" on GetHealth class.

```
GameControl gameControl = new GameControl();
```

Is there another way to solve this without "new".

Comment: You need to make the classes static. I think that's what you want.

Comment: It should be noted that you can achieve your own value types with structs. Doing this you can init them with "MyStruct = 31". May not be what you're looking for, but it can be useful in the right situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If instantiation of player was in `updateStat` method and it is calling in `void update()` method, it cause to instantiate player object again and again. You can try this or instantiate `playerclass2` in constructor. Also making health and experience `static` will help if only player object exist.

```
Class StatClass{
  PlayerClass playerclass2;
  public float health2;
  public float experience2;

  public void updateStat(){
     if(playerclass2==null) playerclass2 = new PlayerClass();
     health2 = playerclass2.health;
     experience2 = playerclas2.experience;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can't use new keyword since it is derived from `MonoBehavior`. Have to use `ClassName.method()` format to call methods of derived classes from `MonoBehavior`

Comment: Note that it should read "public" and not "publuc". Simple typo.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, I have Found it.

It just have to

```
health = GameControl.control.health;
```

I don't have to instantiate it I just Call class and then initialize of class and then variable of class.

Comment: Well. You can't use `new` keyword since it is derived from mono behavior. Also you can set variables to public and drag and drop components in the inspector.